# Making water evaporate faster using chemicals

Tags: thermodynamics, water, physical-chemistry, evaporation

I've already [seen this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/317824/), and it talks about any means in general. I just wanted to know if any chemical substances can be added to water to make it evaporate faster? Does addition of Edible Salt (Sodium chloride) make it evaporate faster? ( I just heard it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make water evaporate faster, you need some means by which you can increase the *vapor pressure* of water. In the case of salt, dissolving it in water  *decreases* the vapor pressure of the water, by furnishing ions in solution whose company the water molecules enjoy (in a manner of speaking). Since the ions themselves cannot evaporate, this slows down the evaporation rate of the water molecules.

Comment: so no chemicals have been found to increase vapor pressure of water?

Comment: no. anything you could add to water has either no effect or the opposite effect.

Comment: what about sodium? It seems to violently react with water, maybe adding small amount of it would increase water's temperature and help it evaporate faster?

Answer (score 2):

What about an azeotropic mixture? Such as water and ethanol? That reduce the BP of water. So does adding lots of HCl to water. 38% HCl in water has a BP of 48 degC.

Comment: One thing I learned in chemistry was don't drink the pure lab alcohol (ethanol). You can't distil all the water out of the ethanol because it forms an azeotrope at about 91 wt% ethanol. The only way to separate all the water from the ethanol is to add benzene. There are usually traces on benzene in the pure ethanol. Benzene is bad for you. To avoid the benzene you need to drink the ultra-pure HPLC grade ethanol. That's very very expensive and the professors get annoyed.

Answer (score 1):

Bob is right from my knowledge and experience: Water evaporates faster if it is mixed with ethanol, as both form an azeotropic mixture (which boils at 80-somewhat °C). We used this in the chemistry lab sometimes when we needed our cleaned glassware faster.
This effect works otherwise round than niels explained for the salt; the ethanol sneaks into the water-water-bonds and weakens them.
As the water-water bonds are also responsible for surface tension, you will also see wetting increasing on most surfaces if you mix ethanol to your water.

If we do not account for chemical effects, niels is right: due to the increased entropy of a mixture compared to a pure component, the melting point of the mixture lowers and the boiling point increases. This effect is much stronger for the melting point, so chemical effects can negate it if they are strong enough.